# JPA query exception unexpected (

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb-3.0, jpa-2.0

Hi this is my entity StudentEntity.java,

```
  @Entity
  @NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="totalStudentSQLQuery",
                query="select count(*) as MAX_STUDENT from tblstudent"),    
    @NamedQuery(name="queryForPagination",
                query="SELECT s.studentid AS studentid, s.studentname AS studentname, s.contactno AS contactno, s.deptid AS deptid "+
                        "FROM (SELECT Row_number() OVER() AS row_num, studentid, studentname, contactno, deptid FROM   tblstudent order by studentId asc) s" +
                        " WHERE  s.row_num >=:minRow AND s.row_num <=:maxRow")
  })
  @Table(name="TBLSTUDENT")
  public class StudentEntity implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 100034222342L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="STUDENTID")
    private Integer studentId;

    @Column(name="STUDENTNAME")
    private String studentName;

    @Column(name="CONTACTNO")
    private String contactNumber;
    .....
    .....

  }
```

I am using Hibernate 4.0 jars for persistence provider, and using JPA ,

My persistense.xml is as follows,

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
               version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="forPractise" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/app</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.entity.StudentEntity</class>
        <class>com.entity.DeptEntity</class>
        <properties>
                <property name="hibernate.dialect"  value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"  />
                <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
                <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />               
            </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
  </persistence>
```

Now when i create a war file of this project and try to deploy in Glassfish server, i get an error 
 unexpected token: (
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 116 [SELECT s.studentid AS studentid, s.studentname AS studentname, s.contactno AS contactno, s.deptid AS deptid FROM   (SELECT Row_number() OVER() AS row_num, studentid, studentname, contactno, deptid FROM   tblstudent order by studentId asc) s WHERE  s.row_num >=:minRow AND s.row_num <=:maxRow]

can anybody tell me were i am doing the mistake in the NamedQuery,

I am using Derby database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the classic SQL database dipendent you have to annotate your query with 
@NamedNativeQuery.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are using a standard SQL query. For NamedQueries you have to define your queries using JPA-QL.